# Chrome gradient background have some color block

Tags: google-chrome, html, background, gradient

Please help me,

When I refresh [this](http://www.ddcs.com.tw/kukofashion/product/goods_detail.php?goods_id=77) page, and this page will become look like the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAMSN.jpg).

But when I press `Ctrl+` or `Ctrl-`, this will be fine.
Is it Chrome's bug? Or something I can fix?

Sorry my English is poor.